# How can I defined as Default checked in a checkbox with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have tried all that I have read in other questions and they did not answer me the problem.

I have a checkbox like this in a list

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="post.rut">
```

I have the model defined like this:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            selected: []
        }
      }
```

The problem  is that If I add checked as default.. it does not change at all I mean it keeps the checkbox not checked

```
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="post.rut" checked>
```

If I remove the v-model, it works BUT I can not send the value to the controller because I need the v-model to bind so I wonder how can I set as default checked in that checkbox input like that?

Thanks

Comment: you dont need `selected` just use `<input type="checkbox" v-model="post.rut">`, if `post.rut` is not boolean, i.e its 0 or 1, yes, no then use `true-value="yes"` / `false-value="no"` etc RTM: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox-1

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which field you want to selected based on the post you can do like so:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            selected: [this.post.rut]
```

Comment: It shows me this error: ReferenceError: post is not defined

Comment: I updated the answer, your object is binded to the vue instance so you need this to assign it (I guess is a prop)

Comment: No it did not work :( If I add that data function stops to work

Comment: What is RUT in the template? Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

you have the input value as `post.rut` you can put it in `selected` array in data like :

```
data: function() {
    return {
        selected: [this.post.rut]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what you asked for.
**Note**: You need not use `v-model` and `:value` at the same time since `v-model` itself is a two way binder.

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
  return {
    selected: true
  };
 },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected"/>
</div>
```